# Оформление цитат. Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация, цитирование, оформление-цитат

Cкaжитe, пожалуйста, пpaвильнo ли oфopмлeны цитaты, представленные нижe, нyжнa ли тoчкa в кoнцe?

1. "Труд - oтeц cчacтья" (Бенджамин Франклин).
2. "Труд - oтeц cчacтья!" (Бенджамин Франклин).
3. "Труд - oтeц cчacтья..." (Бенджамин Франклин).

Я взяла для примера одно предложение, но знаки препинания разные, чтобы не задавать один и тот же вопрос. Пожалуйста, подскажите. Буду очень благодарна!

Answer (score 2):

**Заголовок**
В конце заголовка точка не ставится (вместо дефиса необходимо тире).
*«Труд — oтeц cчacтья...» (Бенджамин Франклин)*

**Эпиграф**
Кавычки и скобки не используются.

> Если указание на автора или цитируемый источник помещается ниже цитаты, в частности при эпиграфах, то скобки снимаются, как и кавычки при цитате, а в конце цитаты ставится знак, соответствующий данному предложению.

```
    ... Почему так часто  
    Мне жаль весь мир и человека жаль?
                                Н. Заболоцкий

    Труд — oтeц cчacтья! 
                     Бенджамин Франклин
```

**Текст**
Цитаты оформлены правильно.

> Ссылки на автора и источник цитирования заключаются в скобки; точка, заканчивающая цитату, ставится после закрывающей скобки. Например: *«Мыслить педагогически широко — это значит уметь видеть в любом социальном явлении воспитательный смысл» (Азаров Ю. Учиться, чтобы учить// Новый мир. 1987. № 4. С. 242).*

*«Труд — oтeц cчacтья» (Бенджамин Франклин).*

> Если цитата заканчивается вопросительным или восклицательным знаком, а также многоточием, то эти знаки сохраняют свое место (стоят перед закрывающей кавычкой). При перечислении примеров точка после закрывающей скобки заменяется на точку с запятой: *«Как ты таинственна, гроза!» (И. Бунин. Полями пахнет...); «Не покидайте своих возлюбленных. Былых возлюбленных на свете нет...» (А. Вознесенский. Поэмы. М., 2001. С. 5).*

*«Труд — oтeц cчacтья!» (Бенджамин Франклин).

«Труд — oтeц cчacтья...» (Бенджамин Франклин).*

[Знаки препинания при цитатах](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139)

Comment: Здравствуйте, Римма Михайловна! Благодарю за подробный ответ, очень нужная информация! А если цитата идет перед основным текстом, но не является заголовком и эпиграфом, все равно ведь точка в конце нужна? Просто выделена, так сказать, по желанию автора, но не выбивается из контекста и идет после заголовка. Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Если это авторская задумка такая (в начале главы, допустим), то в тексте точка нужна. P. S. Римма Михайлова я.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, Римма Михайловна, Вы мне очень помогли! Да, в начале главы цитата, но оформлена отдельно от текста, то есть как бы с отступом небольшим. Далее уже идет сам текст с новой строки.